# Where is TextEdit located in Catalina, on OSX?

Tags: macos-catalina

I thought I'd find it in /Applications but `ls /Applications` doesn't show it.

Are there other locations where apps are stored?

Comment: `~/Applications` but I wouldn't expect it in there

Comment: As you suspected it is not there either.